# Get only one solution for sibling pairs in family tree

Tags: prolog

I have the following Prolog code, modified from Wikipedia:

```
mother_child(trude, sally).

father_child(tom, sally).
father_child(tom, erica).
father_child(mike, tom).

different(X, Y)    :- X \== Y.

sibling(X, Y)      :- parent_child(Z, X), parent_child(Z, Y), different(X, Y).

parent_child(X, Y) :- father_child(X, Y).
parent_child(X, Y) :- mother_child(X, Y).
```

I get the following:

```
?- sibling(X, Y).
X = sally,
Y = erica ;
X = erica,
Y = sally ;
false.
```

Is it possible to modify my code so that `?- sibling(X, Y)` to return ***only***: `X = sally, y = erica ; false.`? That is, I want to eliminate instances where X = Y and Y = X (converse).

Comment: Try replacing `different(X, Y)` in your `sibling/2` predicate with `X @< Y`. That will ensure different without the symmetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by @lurker says it all. Ask yourself what it is that the query is asking:

- Is there a pair X, Y such that:

  - X has the parent Z:

    - Z is a father
    - Z is a mother
  - Y has the parent Z:

    - Z is a father
    - Z is a mother
  - X and Y are not the same

In your current database, a child can have at most one mother and one father, so the two clauses of `parent_child/2` happen to be mutually exclusive for a single child.

But you have the subgoal `parent_child/2` **twice** in `sibling/2`, so for every pair of siblings, you can have *either one of the two* in the first, and then the other one in the second, so you have two proofs for each pair. Saying `X @< Y` instead of `X \== Y` will make sure that only one of the two possible combinations of X and Y lead to a successful proof.

Comment: I did this (`sibling(X, Y) :- parent_child(Z, X), parent_child(Z, Y), X @< Y.`), which yielded `X = erica, Y = sally ; X = erica, Y = sally ; false.` What's going on now?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien when I ran the code you posted in your problem statement, just changing in the `X @< Y`, I only saw one solution, as desired. Did you change anything else in the process? Please check your work.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Same here, I only get `X = erica, Y = sally ; false.`. I copied your code verbatim, then removed the definition of `different/2` completely, and replaced `different(X, Y)` with `X @< Y` in `sibling/2`. Did you _add_ the new definition of `sibling/2` alongside the old one?